# Chrome is Rejecting my URL valid Patterns

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am getting a manafest error from Google Chrome when I update my extension:

`Permission '*://www.dndbeyond.com/homebrew/*' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.`

Ive tried dozens of patterns (including but not limited to `https://www.dndbeyond.com/homebrew/*`, `https://www.dndbeyond.com/homebrew/creations/magic-items/2909810-ashandarei/edit`, `*://*dndbeyond.com/homebrew/*`, `"https://www.dndbeyond.com/"`) and a few straight-up URLs and all are rejected. Why? How do I fix this? Is there a rule I am missing?

Here is the permissions part of my manifest.json:

```json
{
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "scripting",
    "*://www.dndbeyond.com/homebrew/*"
  ],
...
}
```

Comment: Yes! thank you SO much. post it as an answer an I will accept it.

Comment: Flag it as dupe instead, that way Google will still index your question to help others find this the way you phrase it, and visitors will be redirected to the main question.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405110/how-to-accept-another-question-as-duplicate-of-ones-own-question